# Optimal render settings for embedding iOS video in an app

Tags: ios, mobile

I've created some videos for an iOS app and am rendering them through Adobe Media Encoder 2017. These videos are then being played in app through [iOS AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer).

What render settings are best for minimum file size while also maintaining good quality?

Here are the default settings that I'm currently using:
[image: Render settings]

I've rendered cropped versions of the file with confusing results:

- 750 x 1334 full screen, 7 seconds, 5.6 MB
- 590 x 1000 cropped out most white space, 7 seconds, 6.1 MB
- 506 x 904 cropped out all static content, 7 seconds, 6.3 MB

Bonus points for why the video size is increasing as the video screen size is decreased.